# In python lambda expression is fast or the normal function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, lambda

Can Anyone explain which is faster? What are the advantages or disadvantages of using lambda?

Comment: It's a shortcut for writing function. Execution will be almost same.

Comment: Only use lambda for *anonymous functions*, for example, like a key function to pass to `sorted()`

Answer (score 1):

Let's create very simple functions; one as a normal Python function and one using lambda.

```
# Lambda Function
foo = lambda x: x

# Normal Python function
def bar(x):
    return x
```

Now compare the execution time of both the functions using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module:

```
>>> import timeit

# `timeit` measurement of Lambda function
>>> timeit.timeit("foo(123)", setup="from __main__ import foo")
0.0789480209350586

# `timeit` measurement of Normal Python function
>>> timeit.timeit("bar(123)", setup="from __main__ import bar")
0.07846808433532715
```

As you see, execution time of both the function is *almost same*.